# Attempting to add a button_tag in rails causes unexpected tIDENTIFIER syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm developing a rails application and it is my goal to add a button that performs a javascript onclick function. The code that I am using is:

```
<%= button_tag "Action" type: "button", onclick: "test()", class: 'btn btn-default'%>
```

Which I am led to believe is the proper method of doing this. however this causes me to receive the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/users/new.html.erb:28: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...pend=( button_tag "Action" type: 'button', onclick: "test()"...
```

The line of code immediately before is innocent enough:

```
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
```

and additionally I can replace the button tag with other code and it will function without error. My searching implied to me the error may have been caused by copying the code from an online source so I have retyped the line of code by hand with no success. Next I thought perhaps I am just not allowed to place button_tag in a form. However placing this code anywhere else on my website triggers the same error.

I'm really pulling my hair out over this one, any help is appreciated! I am running ruby 2.3.4p301 and rails 5.1.2 if that is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you need a comma after `"Action"`, so `button_tag "Action", type:` ...

Comment: I can't believe it! So much time wasted, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
<%= button_tag "Action", type: "button", onclick: "test()", class: 'btn btn-default'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after `"Action"`